# How to get a list of objects from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

so I have a list of members (MemberObject) on my Firebase and I'm trying to read them with dataSnapshot.getValue..

The firebase looks like this:

[image]

I have MemberObject class looks sort of like this:

```
public class MemberObject {    
    private String mail;
    private String name;
    ...
```

And I'm trying to read the whole member list into this:

```
List<MemberObject> members = dataSnapshot.child("members").getValue(List<MemberObject>.class);
```

unfortunately this doesn't work as is..

The compiler isn't accepting the `List<MemberObject>.class` thing..
It says:

> Cannot select from  parameterized type

What's the right way to do that?

P.S: Just to clear things up, this "members" tree is a leaf under big tree full of "members" leaves so I can't create another `addChildEventListener` inside every leaf

Comment: What you're reading is not a **list** of members. It's a map, from a string key to a member. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31137487/retrieving-data-from-firebase

Comment: Refer to this question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30933328/how-to-convert-firebase-data-to-java-object

Comment: Thank you for the links, I have also found another solution using getChildren method like this: 
`for(DataSnapshot member_i : dataSnapshot.child("members").getChildren())
                    members.add(member_i.getValue(MemberObject.class));`
(after I initialize the list using this:)
`List<MemberObject> members = new ArrayList<>(); `