# Firebase can't retrieve arraylist (use genericTypeIndicator instead?)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im getting an exception of

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class java.util.ArrayList has generic type parameters, please use GenericTypeIndicator instead

I'm not really sure why? its an `ArrayList` of String btw. (The exception doesn't show me which one though, but I only got some and all of them are an `ArrayList<String>`).

Some code examples,

```
public String name;
public ArrayList<String> devicesId;
public DeviceAlarm categoryAlarm;

public Category(){

}

public Category(String name) {
    devicesId = new ArrayList<>();
    this.name = name;
}
```

Thx for helps andd comments!

Comment: Nothing in this code is related to Firebase. Please share the [minimum, complete code that reproduces your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This should probably also include a snippet of your JSON (as text, no screenshots) so that we can see what you're trying to load.

Comment: If you're looking for an example of how to use `GenericTypeIndicator`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31137487/retrieving-data-from-firebase

Comment: Thx for the comments, For some reason now its working already... Still tracing whats went wrong before..