# How to use firebase database in android.?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new in android i want to know what is use of firebase database. And how can I use this database.?

How I store data in this database and how to access data from that database.?

Answer (score 2):

first you should dig into some research and then ask question.

> But AFAIK **firebase** lacks documentation. So I will try to explain steps to it.

read [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup), and use updated Method [**from here**](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android)

1. First of all go to [**firebase Console**](https://console.firebase.google.com/) and create a project(give it name and location)
2. If you want to **read write data without Authentication** steps then change rules in firebase console like

   ```
   {
      "rules": 
      {
         ".read": true,
         ".write": true
      }
   }
   ```
3. If you want to add firebase manually. Go to project settings and select android. give `packageName` , where name and **SHA-1** is optional. download `google-service.json` and in android studio change it's view to Project and paste it under app folder.
4. Add below dependency to **project build.gradle**

   ```
   dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
         classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
   }
   ```

   and at app **Level build.gradle.**

   ```
   dependencies {       
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
   }
   ```

   //add it at the bottom of app level build.gradle

   **apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'**
5. Add **internet permission** in `Manifest`
6. and to set data to firebase Use

   ```
       FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
       DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("rootNode "); // yourwebisteurl/rootNode if it exist otherwise don't pass any string to it.

       myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");
   ```

   or

   ```
      DatabaseReference database = 
      FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
      DatabaseReference ref = database.child("rootNode");//if rootNode exist
      database.setValue("TestRefValue");
   ```

**Note**

i. Upgrade `Google Play Services` and `Google Repository`

> Some Helpful links for reading Database from Firebase.

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31145154/3496570) and [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase documentation is a good place to start, but if you need tutorials to get started with Firebase I recommend the Firebase essentials course from Udacity and Google :

https://www.udacity.com/course/firebase-essentials-for-android--ud009

It's free and there's two major course content updates coming soon.

Answer (score 1):

I think firecast are the most helpful resources available there as a quick start to firebase and they are pretty nicely done. Check this out it helped me a lot when i stated with firebase https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B1rlT5KQ0yE